# Warning: include(dbconn.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site that I am have several issues with. I am not sure if the hosting company did changed something or the site was hacked. I hope this is OK as I have listed a list of errors when a user tries to register for the site. This is also happening when a user tries to use the search function, however in the search function the errors appear at the top and then the search results actually display below. The registration page does not show anything but the following errors.

```
Warning: include(dbconn.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/hoapres/public_html/users/register/index.php on line 26

Warning: include(dbconn.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/hoapres/public_html/users/register/index.php on line 26

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'dbconn.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home1/hoapres/public_html/users/register/index.php on line 26

Warning: include(functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/hoapres/public_html/users/register/index.php on line 27

Warning: include(functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/hoapres/public_html/users/register/index.php on line 27

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home1/hoapres/public_html/users/register/index.php on line 27

Fatal error: Call to undefined function userText2Web() in /home1/hoapres/public_html/users/register/index.php on line 40
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is include path you have used is not correct.
Please check your code where you have include the files like

```
include("dbconn.php");
```

you can try by this way

```
$fullpath = "http://yourdomain.com/";
```

if the dbconn.php is under any folder then

```
$fullpath = "http://yourdomain.com/foldername/";

include($fullpath."dbconn.php");
```

Comment: Includes should use file paths, not URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your directory structure it is tricky to offer a precise answer, but the first thing I would do before trying to include files is to explicitly set your include path.

Assuming that the site root ( `DOCUMENT_ROOT` ) is `/home1/hoapres/public_html` and you have a folder for storing all your include files called `includes`, the path would be `/home1/hoapres/public_html/includes`

```
<?php

   set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes' );
   if( !realpath( get_include_path() ) ) exit('Bad path');

   /* Test to see what files exist perhaps */
   print_r( glob( get_include_path() . '/*.*' ) );

   /* Can you see the files you expect? */
   include 'dbconn.php';
   include 'functions.php';

?>
```